# C- Reading stdin and putting values in an array

Tags: c, arrays, stdin

I have a question regarding stdin and putting the values it reads in an array. I wrote code where it would ask for the size of the array and the values it wants to input. However, I wanna know if there is a way if I can skip this all together and just make stdin read from a text file. Something like

5

5 5 5 5 5

So the  first line is the size of the array and the second line is the values that will be in the array.

This is what I have:

```
      int size,y;

      printf("Enter size of array: ");

      scanf("%d",&size);
      V->size=size;
      V->item=malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
      printf("size of array: %d\n",V->size);

      for(int i =0 ;i < size; i++){
      printf("Enter your value: \n");
      scanf("%d", &y);
      V->item[i]=y;
```

Comment: So you want to read from a file instead of stdin? `cat file | ./MyBinary` will redirect `cat`'s output to your binary input. If you want to directly read the text file from your program, you should learn about `fopen()` and `fscanf()`.

Comment: `V->item = malloc(size * sizeof(int *));` --> `malloc(size * sizeof *(V->item));`.  It appears code is allocating for an array of pointers when `V->item[i]=y` implies a need for an array of `int`.

Comment: @chux woops ! Forgot to put the last 5.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read from a file or from Stdin ? This is not the same thing.

You can redirect the content of a file to stdin by putting it on a pipe like:

```
cat yourfile | ./YourBinary
```

OR

if you want to read directly from the file, I recommend to use ***open(fd, flags)*** function, which return you a file descriptor to the file that you want to open if you got the requiered rights on it. [Here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=open&sektion=2) is the open's man page.

OR

To read from stdin you'll have to use the ***read(fd, buf, buf_size)*** function, like that:

```
char buff[1024];
while(read(filedescriptor, buff, 1023) > 0)
```

Filedescriptor is an integer that can be given by the ***open(fd, flags)*** function if you're trying to open a file, or simply put 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, and 2 for stderr if you want to read one of them.

I puted 1023 on read because you have to keep a char emplacement on your buffer to put the '\0' at the end of your string.